# Bootstrap selectpicker does not show options

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

I have the below simple code that is not working properly.
In fact I'm trying to use [`bootstrap-select - Silvio Moreto`](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) in my project.
It's not showing the options when I click on it.
I narrowed the code to the basic example given by the author but still the same issue.

My code:

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-fr_FR.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Here is what I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: you basic example does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are not including the bootstrap default `CSS` and `JS` files add them and it will work see below demo with the minimum set of files that you need to run. I used `bootstrap 3` as you didn't mention what version you are using if you are using the bootstrap 4 you can add the `popper.min.js` `umd` version.

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```